Why can't I query a Windows 2012 server running SQL Server 2016 from Ubuntu 2404?
I am setting up a machine with Ubuntu 24.04 and am able to query a number of windows servers running SQL Server with no problem - however, there is one server where I get the following error:

[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect

The query I am running is:
isql -v -k 'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;Server=<SERVER>;UID=<USER>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;Database=<DATABASE>;ColumnEncryption=No;TrustServerCertificate=yes'
More details:
Client Machine:
Ubuntu 24.04
Open SSL version 3.0.13
ODBC Driver: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Server Machine:
Windows 2012
MS SQLServer 2016

Does this answer your question? Error: TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746. During the Sql setup in linux through terminal

has your target sql a named instance ? and those you can connect to have default instance (no name) ? - I had a same kind of unclear error message because linux cannot resolve windows named instance = you have to provide ip address and port num

Modern SQL Server connection drivers (.NET, JDBC, ODBC, OLE DB) all require TLS 1.2 protocol support as a minimum for encrypted connections. Windows Server 2012 didn't ship with TLS 1.2 support out of the box, it required service packs, cumulative updates and SChannel registry tweaking. Is your WS2012 server up to date?

The ubuntu server is not having trouble connecting to named sql servers - thanks though @jjdesign
